# Retrieving messages of which I am a sender, receiver, based on the user id

Tags: javascript

I have an array called `messages`. When I send a message I am `sender`, when I receive it I am `receiver`. My 'id' is '6003123'. What's the easiest way to get messages that are `sender`, `receiver` and related to my `id`? Is the following way and the use of the `filter` method appropriate?

```
const messages = [
  {
    _id: '610be2c',
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdsdsd' },
    sender: '608ffae',  
    receiver: '6003123'  **//myId**
  },
  {
    _id: '610be2d',
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd' },
    sender: '6003123',   **//myId**
    receiver: '608ffae'
  },
  {
    _id: '610be2dert',
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd' },
    sender: '6003123',  **//myId**
    receiver: '608ffae'
  },
  {
    _id: '610be2dertrtyu',
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdffgghghgh' },
    sender: '3456',  
    receiver: '098765'
  },
  {
    _id: '610be2dertrtyu',
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdffgghghgh' },
    sender:  '098765'
    receiver: '3456'
  } 
] 

const myId = '6003123';


let messagesArray = messages.filter(message => message.sender === myId && message.receiver === myId) || message.sender === myId || message.receiver === myId));
```

Comment: `_id: 610be2dert,` this is invalid data. Should be `_id: "610be2dert",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `.filter()` and only one `||` OR operator
- Fix your Object data strings

```js
const messages = [
  {
    _id: "610be2c",
    msg: { text: "sdsdsdsdsd" },
    sender: "608ffae",  
    receiver: "6003123",
  }, {
    _id: "610be2d",
    msg: { text: 'sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd' },
    sender: "6003123", 
    receiver: "608ffae"
  }, {
    _id: "610be2dert",
    msg: { text: "sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd" },
    sender: "6003123",
    receiver: "608ffae"
  }, {
    _id: "610be2dertrtyu",
    msg: { text: "sdsdsdffgghghgh" },
    sender: "3456",  
    receiver: "098765",
  }, {
    _id: "610be2dertrtyu",
    msg: { text: "sdsdsdffgghghgh" },
    sender:  "098765",
    receiver: "3456",
  } 
];

const getMessagesWhereSenderReceiver = (id) => messages.filter(msg => {
  return msg.sender === id ||  msg.receiver === id;
});

console.log(getMessagesWhereSenderReceiver("6003123"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
let messagesArray = messages.filter(message => message.sender === myId || message.receiver === myId));
```

is what you're looking for.